# Login system don't want to log on web page

Tags: php, sql, session, authentication

I created a login system for my web page.
On localhost when i enter my username and password and click to login it works. 
When i do it on the live site, nothing happend.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

$password=$_POST['password'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password_hash=md5($password);

if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
$query= "SELECT id FROM studenti WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' AND password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password_hash)."'";
if($query_run=mysql_query($query)){
$query_num = mysql_num_rows($query_run);

if($query_num==0){

echo '<div class="text1">Pogresan Username/Password</div>';

}else if ($query_num==1){

$user_id=mysql_result($query_run,0, 'id');
$_SESSION['user_id']=$user_id;
header('Location : index.php');

}
}
}else{
echo '<div class="text2">Morate upisati Username i  Password</div>';

}
}

?>
```

Here you can try it [EXAMPLE](http://stefanvblog.com/ispiti/index.php) Registraion works ok, and all users are in datebase, also my password field in datebase is 35 char long.. (md5). I don't see where is problem..

This is code of registration :

```
<?php
require 'core.php';
require 'connectdb.php';

if(!loggedin()){

if(
    isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['password_again'])&& isset($_POST['username'])&& isset($_POST['ime'])&& isset($_POST['prezime'])){

$password=$_POST['password'];
$password_again=$_POST['password_again'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$ime=$_POST['ime'];
$prezime=$_POST['prezime'];
$password_hash=md5($password);

if(!empty($password) && !empty($password_again)&& !empty($username)&& !empty($ime)&& !empty($prezime)){

if($password!=$password_again){

echo '<div class="text2">Passwordi se ne poklapaju :)</div>';

}else{

$query="SELECT username FROM studenti WHERE username='$username'";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)==1){

echo '<div class="text2">Korisnicko ime'.' '.$username.' '.'vec postoji</div>';
}else{
$query="INSERT INTO studenti VALUES ('','".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($password_hash)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($ime)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($prezime)."')";
if($query_run=mysql_query($query)){

header('Location: uspjeh.php');

}else{
    echo '<div class="text2">Dogodila se greska, probaj kasnije!</div>';
}
}
}
}else{

    echo '<div class="text4">Popuni sva polja</div>';
}
}
    ?>
```

Here is my all code in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/R7tyvCXZ) 
My server use PHP version 5.3.26 so i don't need to use mysqli_connect();

Comment: Don't use MD5 for hashing passwords. It's broken and is insecure.

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot this? There's a lot of code here which makes me think you didn't do enough debugging yet.

Comment: So where's your [session_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)?

Comment: where is `session_start()` ?

Comment: add `session_start()` on top of your login script.

Comment: OK, here is my all code.. can you please look it.. pastebin.com/R7tyvCXZ all works.. just.. that problem is very wirde..

Comment: WHY THE HELL do you still use md5 in the year 2014 ? I mean, why don't you even read into the absolute basics ? And you use mysql_, which is also outdated for years. I would fire you instantly for this.

Comment: You have not helped. I do not know what you wanted to achieve with that comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `connectdb.php` in the first file (require/include)! Maybe you got no database connection.

You must set `session_start()` at the beginning of each file that uses the `$_SESSION[]` variable.

And you should switch to [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), because mysql is deprecated and will be removed in newer versions of PHP.

With `mysql_real_escape_string()` you only got basic security. Take a look at [prepared statements (mysqli)](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) / [prepared statements (PDO)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

And you must escape values in every query, including "SELECT". (For example the `$username`)

Comment: OK, here is my all code.. can you please look it.. http://pastebin.com/R7tyvCXZ  all works.. just.. that problem is very wirde..